# C++ Tic-Tac-Toe User Input Assignment

Tags: c++

For some practice I decided to make a console tic-tac-toe game. Here is a snippit from `int main`

```
int main()
{
    //Small 2x2 board (for now), hense the 4 options below
    int op1, op2, op3, op4;

    //Draws the board on the screen, separate function I've made
    board(op1, op2, op3, op4); 

    //asking the user the first option, which is for X not O
    //User will enter 1, 2, 3, or 4 and an X should appear in corresponding quadrant.
    cout << "x? ";
    cin >> op1;
}
```

So what I want to happen is for the board to appear first, and then afterwards have the console ask the user to enter in where to put the X's and the O's.

But what ends up happening here is that the user's option doesn't show up on the board, because the user enters in the option after the board has been loaded rather than before.

How can I overwrite the original assignment of `int op1` to the user's input so that it automatically places it on the board? Thanks!

P.S: I didn't want to cheat an look up source code of a tic-tac-toe game :P

Comment: 1: Draw an *empty* board. 2: Ask for users input. 3. Draw updated board. Etc.

Comment: You mean you want the user's input to change the already drawn board? you can't do that. usually in in-console game, you should draw the board after every move, until game over state is reached.

Comment: Calling board again to redraw is not in the cards?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the user input and update the board state with the latest input by calling your function board again.
Also, I think creating a 2x2 tic-tac-toe isn't a good idea to learn about games because any two moves will end the game. Instead try the standard 3x3 tic tac toe. For this you'll have to implement a new function that checks if the game has been won by a player.

Comment: Thanks, and I made it 2x2 just as sort of a 'rough draft', or a base to work off of. I agree, a 2x2 board game is pretty pointless but I wanted to get the ball rolling and then add more to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use system("CLS") to clear the screen after the user input, cin. and cout after system("CLS"), to display the new edited board with the user's input. This just solves the board to be updated with the user's input :)